# React Native: E unknown:ReactNative: Got DOWN touch before receiving UP or CANCEL from last gesture

Tags: android, react-native

Got next error in ReactNative (android)

- E unknown:ReactNative: Got DOWN touch before receiving UP or CANCEL from last gesture
- PowerWrap: PowerHal_TouchBoost

Screen doesn't react on touch events and looks like freezing, but all background tasks running with success result and debugger doesn't show other errors.

RN 0.63.3
RN-navigation 7.0.0

Edited:

android/settings.gradle

```
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle")
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
```

android/gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.54.0
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        supportLibVersion = "29.0.0"
        kotlinVersion = "1.3.61"
        RNNKotlinVersion = kotlinVersion
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
...
apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle")
applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

MainApplication / MainActivity.java from docs react-native-navigation 7.0

Comment: Please post a minimum reproducible code, expected behavior, and errors. so chaps here can help you out. To ask a good question please follow this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know is it correct, but I found solution on rnn docs:

https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/installing

app/build.gradle

dependencies { ... implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0' implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}" }

Adding this two dependencies solved problem.